# Is it possible to have one application configure and manage a DirectShow filter but have the output pin bound to a different application?

Tags: c#, c++, com, directshow

I'm new to direct show and I'm wondering if this is possible (any additional help to finding a solution would also be nice but I'm more worried about if this is worth pursing).

I am creating a DirectShow source filter in C++ and I'm designing it such that the FillBuffer call gets passed to a C# application. From my understanding the C# application will need to load the DirectShow filter (I plan on using the DirectShowNet library) and then request the interface I created that contains helper methods (to specify the FillBuffer function and configure the media source). This is very similar to the GSSF example on the [DirectShowNet](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html) site.

However, I'm wondering if the act of loading the filter into one application prevents it from being used in another - or if the changes I make to the configuration of the filter will not be reflected if the filter is loaded in a different application.

Like I said I'm not that comfortable with COM or DirectShow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DirectShow filters in a application means building a graph in this application. When you use two applications you would have two graphs, each with its own filter instances.

I'm not sure if you can use one graph in multiple applications. The tool GraphBuilder is able to connect to existing graphs, but this was originally implemented for debug reasons and not for graph sharing.

If you just want to share configuration and could use two filter instances, you could implement a shared configuration (registry, serialized data, ..) and let each filter poll for config changes.

Comment: Thanks so much. That was my alternate solution. Thanks for your insight.